# Using React with pre-loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my scenario.

- I want to load in data from a CMS using React
- The CMS spits out HTML (Webflow)
- I've set up an HTML/CSS page that displays 10 app "screens" all on the one page
- I'd like to get the HTML it spits out, load it into React and then manipulate it with react navigation, swiper etc.

Example:

```
<body>
 <div id="react-target">
    <section id="main">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section2">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section3">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </section>
    <section id="section4">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </section>
 </div>
</body>
```

Is there any way to "reactify" this dom content? I want to take this DOM contents (including the visual representation) and then turn them into swipeable full-screen 'pages', similar to how jQuery / SwiperJS works.

Comment: Have a look at this => https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I've seen this, but isn't `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` used for ... setting the innerHtml in the DOM? I'm not trying to change the DOM this way, I'm trying to load an existing DOM into React and then use it in components.

Comment: do you want to split the HTML above by section and then move around each section with react? You cannot really convert HTML to React JSX, but you can use dangerouslySetInnerHtml to display that HTML in the page.

Alterinative would be https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser but it's quite outdated or https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser which is newer

Comment: I guess by setting your html with dangerouslySetInnerHtml, you'll get the same DOM structure that you're getting in the spitted HTML. You don't have to manipulate anything at frontend side in case I've understood your problem correctly.